# Use of std::forward in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I have come across a code, where `std::forward` is used. I have googled about it for a longtime and not able to understand its real purpose and use.

I have seen similar threads in stackoverflow, but still not clear. Can somebody explain it with a simple example?

PS: I have gone through this [page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/forward/), but still not able to appreciate its use. Please do not flag this question duplicate and rather try to help me out.

Comment: [Read this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward). GMan's answer and expansion on what it is and how to use it is positively outstanding. Your question is (unfortunately) a duplicate of that one, but just read it none-the-less.

Comment: I would suggest the reading of ["C++ Rvalue References Explained"](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html) by Thomas Becker, in particular, the section on perfect forwarding.

Comment: @CassioNeri Thanks. In fact I had difficulty in understanding lvalues and rvalues

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As the page you linked poses it:

> This is a helper function to allow perfect forwarding of arguments
>   taken as rvalue references to deduced types, preserving any potential
>   move semantics involved.

When you have **a named value**, as in

```
void f1(int& namedValue){
    ...
}
```

or in

```
void f2(int&& namedValue){
    ...
}
```

it **evaluates**, no matter what, **to an `lvalue`**.

One more step. Suppose you have a template function

```
template <typename T>
void f(T&& namedValue){
    ...
}
```

such function can either be called with an lvalue or with an rvalue; however, no matter what, namedValue **evaluates to an `lvalue`**.

Now suppose you have two overloads of an helper function

```
void helper(int& i){
    ...
}
void helper(int&& i){
    ...
}
```

calling `helper` from inside `f`

```
template <typename T>
void f(T&& namedValue){
    helper(namedValue);
}
```

will invariably call the first overload for `helper`, since `namedValue` is, well, **a named value** which, naturally, **evaluates to an `lvalue`**.

In order to get the second version called when appropriate (i.e. when `f` has been invoked with a rvalue parameter), you write

```
template <typename T>
void f(T&& namedValue){
    helper( std::forward<T>(namedValue) );
}
```

All of this is expressed much concisely in the documentation by the following

> The need for this function stems from the fact that all named values
>   (such as function parameters) always evaluate as lvalues (even those
>   declared as rvalue references), and this poses difficulties in
>   preserving potential move semantics on template functions that forward
>   arguments to other functions.

Comment: You last example, while it will work, should instead use `std::move`.  It isn't a deduced type, and isn't an example of the purpose of `std::forward`.

Comment: @user1131467 using `std::move` would (potentially) invalidate `namedValue`, hence impeding its use when `helper(std::move(namedValue))` returns.

Comment: As will `std::forward`.  `std::forward` has exactly the same effect as `std::move` in your example, it always produces an xvalue.

Comment: @user1131467 In the documentation for `std::move` I read:  the value of the moved-from object should only be destroyed or assigned a new value. Is there anything similar in the documentation for `std::forward`?

Comment: @user1131467 ok, thanks, please give me some feedback for the revised version

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36807/discussion-between-stefano-falasca-and-user1131467)

Comment: Now that you have changed it from `int&&` to a deduced type "universal reference" `T&&`, it is now a correct use of `std::forward`.

Answer (score 5):

Each expression is in exactly one of the following two value categories: lvalue or rvalue.

Normally if you call a function like:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T t);

template<typename T>
void g(T t)
{
    f(t);
}
```

The value category of the argument to `g` is lost between the call to g and f, because named parameters, like local variables, are always lvalues.

By using `std::forward` and adjusting the parameter to a "universal reference" that uses reference collapsing you can preserve the value category:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T&& t);

template<typename T>
void g(T&& t)
{
    f(forward<T>(t));
}
```

That's why it's called "forward", because you are "forwarding" the value category on, rather than losing it.

So in the example if you call `g` with an rvalue, then f will be called with an rvalue - rather than an lvalue.

Answer (score 1):

It is used to preserve the exact type of an argument in templates when passing it to another function. For example:

```
template<class T>
void wrapper(T&& arg)
{
    foo(std::forward<T>(arg)); // Forward a single argument.
}
```

This works as follows:

- If the function `wrapper` gets a `std::string` or `const std::string&`, then `foo` is called as if `arg` has type of `const std::string&`.
- If the function `wrapper` gets a `std::string&`, then `foo` is called as if `arg` has type of `std::string&`.
- If the function `wrapper` gets a `std::string&&`, then `foo` is called as if `arg` has type of `std::string&&`.

The problem that `std::forward`  solves is that by the usual rules the type of `arg` within function is `std::string` even if we pass `std::string&&` to `wrapper`. `std::forward` allows to *inject* the actual type of `T`, be it `T`, `T&`, `const T&` or `T&&`, to the call site.

Comment: Pretty close, the function gets a prvalue, xvalue or lvalue - expressions (arguments) can never have reference type - so a function can never gets a "string&" or "string&&" as an argument.

Comment: Sorry, it's still not correct.  If I have `string&& arg = ...; wrapper(arg);`, arg is an lvalue, and the forward will be as if `static_cast<T&>(arg)`, not `static_cast<T&&>(arg)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's basic use is you're in function `g` that has been called like this:

```
g(T1 p1, T2 p2, /* ... */);
```

and you want to call function `f` with *exactly* the same types:

```
f(T1 p1, T2 p2, /* ... */);
```