# why child class can convert lvalue to rvalue? in c++ perfect forwarding

Tags: c++

```
using namespace std;

class Data {
public:
    Data() {}
    ~Data() {}

    Data(const Data& t) { cout << "Copy Constructor" << endl; }
    Data(Data&& t) noexcept { cout << "Move Constructor" << endl; }
    Data& operator=(const Data& t) {
        cout << "Copy =" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
    Data& operator=(Data&& t) noexcept {
        cout << "Move =" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

class Data2 : public Data {};

class Test {
public:
    void setData(std::shared_ptr<Data>&& d) { data = std::forward<std::shared_ptr<Data>>(d); }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Data> data;
};

int main() {
    Test t;
    auto d = std::make_shared<Data>();
    t.setData(d); // error
    t.setData(move(d)); // ok

    auto d1 = std::make_shared<Data2>();
    t.setData(d1); // why ok????????????

    int debug = 0;
}
```

Why doesn't `t.setData(d1)` require `std::move` to convert `d1` to an rvalue but `t.setData(d)` doesn't compile?

Comment: Please don't bypass the code to text ratio limits by adding repeated text, explain your problem more clearly instead

Comment: I personally think the downvotes are a tad unfair, but you _are_ approaching this in a complicated way. You may get more answers if you explain why you made `d` want temporaries instead of taking the shared pointer by value.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explain it clearly.  I'll do my best next time.

Answer (score 1):

`t.setData(d1)` has to convert `d1` to `std::shared_ptr<Data>`, it does this by copying into a temporary value. Temporary values are already rvalues so don't require an explicit `std::move`.

Note that as `d1` is passed via a temporary conversion `setData` doesn't alter `d1`, you still need to use `std::move` for this to happen so that `d1` is moved into the temporary rather than being copied. E.g in:

```
auto d = std::make_shared<Data>();
t.setData(std::move(d));
std::cout << d.get() << "\n";

auto d1 = std::make_shared<Data2>();
t.setData(d1);
std::cout << d1.get() << "\n";

auto d2 = std::make_shared<Data2>();
t.setData(std::move(d2));
std::cout << d2.get() << "\n";
```

`d` and `d2` will end up as null pointers but `d1` will still point to the object.

Note that in `std::forward<std::shared_ptr<Data>>(d)` as you know the exact type of `d` `std::forward` [is unnecessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619036/use-of-stdforward-in-c) and you could just use `std::move(d)` instead.

Comment: It really helped me a lot. Thank you.